# How to apply a function while filtering using loc method in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe **A** and dataframe **B** in pandas. I want to update one of A's column based if certain conditions for a row is matched in B. While matching with multiple conditions, I want to apply a function called "**similar**" on the current row like below:

```
def similar(a, b):
    match_ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    if match_ratio > 0.6:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def updateLabel(repo_name, str_a):

    str_to_check = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', str_a)        
    data = B.loc[(B['repo_name'] == repo_name) & similar(B["sanitized_str_b"], str_to_check)]
    
    if len(data) > 0:
        return "TP"
    
    return "FP"
    

A["label"] = A[["repo_name", "str_a"]].apply(lambda x: updateLabel(x.repo_name, x.str_a), axis = 1)
```

However, it throws an error. Then I tried like below but it is very slow.

```
def updateLabel(repo_name, str_a):
    
    str_to_check = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', str_a)
    
    def similar(a):
        match_ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, a, str_to_check).ratio()
        if match_ratio > 0.6:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    data = B.loc[(B['repo_name'] == repo_name)]
    data = B.loc[data.sanitized_str_b.apply(similar)]
    
    if len(data) > 0:
        return "TP"
    
    return "FP"
    

A["label"] = A[["repo_name", "str_a"]].apply(lambda x: updateLabel(x.repo_name, x.str_a), axis = 1)
```

What is the correct way to filter a dataframe with multiple conditions and conditions by calling a function in pandas?

Comment: Is your bottom code block formatted correctly?

Comment: Yes. I have used inner function for similar

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to provide optimization clues if you included a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I see one way to improve speed however: you don't need to filter `data` with `apply(similar)` if you're only checking for its length being >0. Use `any`:

```
def updateLabel(repo_name, str_a):
    
    str_to_check = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', str_a)
    
    def similar(a):
        match_ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, a, str_to_check).ratio()
        if match_ratio > 0.6:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    data = B.loc[(B['repo_name'] == repo_name)]
    
    if any(similar(x) for x in data.sanitized_str_b):
        return "TP"
    
    return "FP"
    

A["label"] = A[["repo_name", "str_a"]].apply(lambda x: updateLabel(x.repo_name, x.str_a), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to "fuzzy match" the `str` columns.

There are faster options compared to `SequenceMatcher` e.g. [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) - there are various pandas/rapidfuzz examples on stackoverflow.

As you also want an equality match on the `repo_name`, you could use something that supports both operations natively e.g. [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html)

```
import duckdb
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame({"repo_name": [1, 2, 3, 4], "str_a": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "omg"]}).reset_index()
B = pd.DataFrame({"repo_name": [2, 3, 4, 2, 3], "sanitized_str_b": ["car", "daz", "gmo", "far", "ggg"]}).reset_index()
```

```
>>> A
   index  repo_name str_a
0      0          1   foo
1      1          2   bar
2      2          3   baz
3      3          4   omg
```

```
>>> B
   index  repo_name sanitized_str_b
0      0          2             car
1      1          3             daz
2      2          4             gmo
3      3          2             far
4      4          3             ggg
```

duckdb can [read from pandas dataframes](https://duckdb.org/2021/05/14/sql-on-pandas.html):

```
duckdb.sql("""
from A left join B
on 
   A.repo_name = B.repo_name
   and
   jaro_winkler_similarity(str_a, sanitized_str_b) > .6
select 
   distinct on (A.repo_name) *
order by A.index
""")
```

You could then assign the `TP/FP` result based on the `NULL` values.

```
┌───────┬───────────┬─────────┬───────┬───────────┬─────────────────┐
│ index │ repo_name │  str_a  │ index │ repo_name │ sanitized_str_b │
│ int64 │   int64   │ varchar │ int64 │   int64   │     varchar     │
├───────┼───────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────────┼─────────────────┤
│     0 │         1 │ foo     │  NULL │      NULL │ NULL            │
│     1 │         2 │ bar     │     0 │         2 │ car             │
│     2 │         3 │ baz     │     1 │         3 │ daz             │
│     3 │         4 │ omg     │  NULL │      NULL │ NULL            │
└───────┴───────────┴─────────┴───────┴───────────┴─────────────────┘
```

- [`jaro_winkler_similarity()`](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/char.html#text-similarity-functions) is used as the scorer.
- [`.df()`](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html#result-conversion) can be used to turn the result into a pandas dataframe